# Compiling LINQ expressions

Tags: linq, compiler-construction, f#, expression, f#-3.0

I'm wondering what steps the (v3+) compiler takes to build LINQ expressions for methods that take an expression argument.  In particular, does the compiler use, or share logic with, [`LeafExpressionConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323986.aspx)? (That could require first generating an `Expr` then converting it.) If there is a separate mechanism, is anything done to ensure parity with `LeafExpressionConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe that it uses `LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToLambdaExpression`.  Search for `quote_to_linq_lambda_info` in the open source compiler code base.

Comment: [Found it](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/4493a116ba6862ff0c1d08b7e1c73c6ff8b4e8af/src/fsharp/env.fs#L945). Thanks.